# gcc: enforce memory layout < 32bit

Tags: gcc, mingw-w64

I got a historic mingw64 folder (SET A) under Windows, where nobody really knows what it includes.

I just created with MSYS2 another mingw64 (SET B) installation and compared the outputs.

For both I created the following file:

```
/* file.c */
int main(void)
{
  return 0;
}
```

With both tool chains I compile by:

```
gcc file.c -o binary.exe
```

When I compare those binaries via `objdump -h binary.exe`, I get different memory maps:

```
========================
SET A (historic BLOB)
========================
binary.exe:     file format pei-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         00001d10  0000000000401000  0000000000401000  00000400  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  1 .data         00000090  0000000000403000  0000000000403000  00002200  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .rdata        000005e0  0000000000404000  0000000000404000  00002400  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .pdata        00000234  0000000000405000  0000000000405000  00002a00  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .xdata        00000200  0000000000406000  0000000000406000  00002e00  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .bss          000009d0  0000000000407000  0000000000407000  00000000  2**5
                  ALLOC
  6 .idata        000007ac  0000000000408000  0000000000408000  00003000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  7 .CRT          00000068  0000000000409000  0000000000409000  00003800  2**3
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  8 .tls          00000068  000000000040a000  000000000040a000  00003a00  2**5
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
```

```
========================
SET B (fresh MSYS2 BLOB)
========================
binary.exe:     file format pei-x86-64

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA               LMA               File off  Algn
  0 .text         000016c8  0000000140001000  0000000140001000  00000600  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE, DATA
  1 .data         00000090  0000000140003000  0000000140003000  00001e00  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  2 .rdata        00000a50  0000000140004000  0000000140004000  00002000  2**4
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .pdata        00000210  0000000140005000  0000000140005000  00002c00  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  4 .xdata        0000018c  0000000140006000  0000000140006000  00003000  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  5 .bss          00000180  0000000140007000  0000000140007000  00000000  2**4
                  ALLOC
  6 .idata        00000510  0000000140008000  0000000140008000  00003200  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  7 .CRT          00000060  0000000140009000  0000000140009000  00003800  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  8 .tls          00000010  000000014000a000  000000014000a000  00003a00  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  9 .rsrc         000004e8  000000014000b000  000000014000b000  00003c00  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 10 .reloc        00000078  000000014000c000  000000014000c000  00004200  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
 11 .debug_aranges 00000410  000000014000d000  000000014000d000  00004400  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 12 .debug_info   00009b76  000000014000e000  000000014000e000  00004a00  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 13 .debug_abbrev 00001c09  0000000140018000  0000000140018000  0000e600  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 14 .debug_line   00001b96  000000014001a000  000000014001a000  00010400  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 15 .debug_frame  000007f0  000000014001c000  000000014001c000  00012000  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 16 .debug_str    000002c3  000000014001d000  000000014001d000  00012800  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 17 .debug_line_str 00001560  000000014001e000  000000014001e000  00012c00  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 18 .debug_loclists 000011fc  0000000140020000  0000000140020000  00014200  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
 19 .debug_rnglists 00000195  0000000140022000  0000000140022000  00015400  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY, DEBUGGING
```

Sadly I have a use case, where I rely on the fact that the memory addresses are < 32 bit.

Is there a gcc option so that SET B (fresh MSYS2 BLOB) generates a similar memory map like SET A?

```
========================
SET A (historic BLOB)
========================
$ gcc -v
Reading specs from d:/tools/mingw64/bin/../lib64/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/specs
COLLECT_GCC=D:\Tools\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=d:/tools/mingw64/bin/../libexec/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.8.3/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-4.8.3/configure --prefix=/opt/windows_64 --with-sysroot=/opt/windows_64 --libdir=/opt/windows_64/lib64 --mandir=/opt/windows_64/man --infodir=/opt/windows_64/info --enable-shared --disable-bootstrap --disable-multilib --enable-threads=posix --enable-languages=c,c++ --enable-checking=release --enable-libgomp --with-system-zlib --with-python-dir=/lib64/python2.7/site-packages --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-__cxa_atexit --enable-libssp --with-gnu-ld --verbose --enable-java-home --with-java-home=/opt/windows_64/lib64/jvm/jre --with-jvm-root-dir=/opt/windows_64/lib64/jvm --with-jvm-jar-dir=/opt/windows_64/lib64/jvm/jvm-exports --with-arch-directory=amd64 --with-antlr-jar='/home/adrien/projects/win-builds-1.5/slackware64-current/d/gcc/antlr-*.jar' --disable-java-awt --disable-gtktest --build=x86_64-slackware-linux --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.8.3 (GCC)

========================
SET B (fresh MSYS2 BLOB)
========================
$ gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=D:\install\msys2\msys2-base-x86_64-20240113.tar\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=D:/install/msys2/msys2-base-x86_64-20240113.tar/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/lto-wrapper.exe
Target: x86_64-w64-mingw32
Configured with: ../gcc-13.2.0/configure --prefix=/mingw64 --with-local-prefix=/mingw64/local --build=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --host=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --target=x86_64-w64-mingw32 --with-native-system-header-dir=/mingw64/include --libexecdir=/mingw64/lib --enable-bootstrap --enable-checking=release --with-arch=nocona --with-tune=generic --enable-languages=c,lto,c++,fortran,ada,objc,obj-c++,jit --enable-shared --enable-static --enable-libatomic --enable-threads=posix --enable-graphite --enable-fully-dynamic-string --enable-libstdcxx-filesystem-ts --enable-libstdcxx-time --disable-libstdcxx-pch --enable-lto --enable-libgomp --disable-libssp --disable-multilib --disable-rpath --disable-win32-registry --disable-nls --disable-werror --disable-symvers --with-libiconv --with-system-zlib --with-gmp=/mingw64 --with-mpfr=/mingw64 --with-mpc=/mingw64 --with-isl=/mingw64 --with-pkgversion='Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project' --with-bugurl=https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues --with-gnu-as --with-gnu-ld --disable-libstdcxx-debug --with-boot-ldflags=-static-libstdc++ --with-stage1-ldflags=-static-libstdc++
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib zstd
gcc version 13.2.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)
```